# After getting log backup from my database the VLF status remain 2 in sql server 2008 r2 SP2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database in SQL server 2008 R2 SP2 and I had set log shipping on that db.
every 5 minutes the transaction log backup is created but when I run dbcc loginfo on my db, the most VLF status are 2 So the shrinkfile('db_log') can not decrease the LDF file size. I'm so confused because after getting log backup (by log shipping) why the VLF status doesn't set to 0?
Even I run checkpoint on my db, but it is not make any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases for your database specifically. You could have an active transaction holding the log, replication, or something else entirely. But that column will point you on the right direction.

Comment: Hi Ben. Thank you for your answer. I had an inactive publication on my databse and after remove that all vlf set to 0.your answer help me alot.

Comment: It's all about learning here. If you found my answer helpful, go ahead and mark it as the answer.